# отличие class от function php

Tags: php, ооп

здравствуйте, программирую на php без нескольких месяцев год, и пока что не могу точно понят в чём преимущество классов по сравнению с функциями, и почему профессионалы  большинстве используют классы?

Объясните пожалуйста доходчиво в чем разница, или может на примере

Comment: заголовок и тело вопроса различны...ибо если утрировать, то класс - обертка над функциями.... а вот относительно тела вопроса "в чем преимущество и почему.." - это надо просто смотреть литературу по ООП и классам

Answer (score 4):

Это очень глубокий и широкий вопрос. Перефразируя, звучит так: в чем отличие [процедурного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) от [объектно-ориентированного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) программирования?

---

В первом случае, во главу угла ставится *действие*, т.е. набор последовательных команд для решения определенной задачи.

В ООП применяется модульный подход, во главе которого стоит объект из реального мира. Т.е. код организован таким образом, что представляет собой набор объектов, каждый из которых решает свою небольшую задачу, а взаимодействуя между собой все эти объекты решают одну общую задачу.

---

[Попытка всё это объяснить на примере PHP](https://habrahabr.ru/post/23619/)

Answer (score 1):

Представим школу.

Ученики это переменные или функции (в классах правильней назвать методами), а школа это Ваш код.
Класс объединяет учеников в группы, тоже самое происходит и в коде.

Плодить кучу функций аля `gruppa_naznachenie1()`, `gruppa_naznachenie2()` не очень удобно.
Тем более можно сделать класс, который будет расширять или изменять возможности другого класса не изменяя его.

Ещё класс удобен тем, что все действия будут происходить внутри него и некоторые ненужные данные не вырвутся дальше него.

А теперь просто зрительно сравним просто процедуры

`echo work_func1("blablabla").$work_var1;`

и работу с классом

`$work = new WorkClass();
echo $work->func1("blablabla").$work->var1;`

Также класс ещё много в чём удобен.
Я не хочу навязывать Вам какое-либо мнение.
Я лично в маленьких проектах работаю процедурно, без мании величия классов.
Попробуйте написать что-нибудь с использованием классов и посмотрите - надо это Вам или нет, может когда-то и пригодится.